# Which car can be sold for the most money when fully modified?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I'm wondering which car that you can find on the street can be sold for most money when it's fully customized. I know that the Futo and the Sultan goes for 100k+ when fully modded but are there any cars that are more expensive?

Answer (score 1):

Along with the Sultan & Futo, there is the Dominator, which is very profitable when fully modified.

The Schafter goes for around $120,000-$130,000 when fully modified, but it is rare.

From what I remember, the Gallivanter Baller and the Lampadati Felon get you $9000 when sold. These are the most common profitable cars to sell non-modified.

It may get you more if you customise it, but I don't see the point in  spending time, only to get a bit more money.

Answer (score -2):

i would assume it might be the adder or any of the new cars that was released with the new update. i dont think you would benefit from them though because you can sell a car that will get you a maximum of 500k more than that it wont allow you to sell it. you can go for the panto many people like it because it is cheap to buy and expensive to sell.

Comment: Is this still true as of the latest Further Adventures in Finance and Felony update?

Comment: You can't find adders on the street.

Comment: You can find the Adder in one specific place, but only in Single-Player. It isn't common though, so it might not be worth the time looking for it.